# ERROR: Cannot access file in Excel publish to webpage setup

Tags: excel, html, publish

I have a very important setup running on Windows XP/Office 2003(Excel)

It's a spreadsheet that when you hit save, it publishes ranges of cells from 2 sheets to a html file.

There is then HTML code that refreshes the publish webpage every 10 seconds.

Layout:

```
    Spreadsheet >>> htm output >>> html file refreshing output every 10 secs to display any changes.
    Book1.xls       output.htm     refresh.html
```

Here is the HTML I use to refresh the output

```
    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">

     <TITLE> None </TITLE>

     <frameset rows="80%,*" cols="20%" bordercolor="#0099FF" id="message" name="message">
<frame id="motd1" scrolling=no name="motd1" src="output.htm"  border="1" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" noresize>

    <frame src="UntitledFrame-7.html">


    </frameset>
    <noframes></noframes>
    </html>
```

I've recently tried to upgrade the systems to Win 7/Office 2010.

For some reason, when the HTML refreshes the output html and save is hit on the spreadsheet at the same time, an error is generated(because the file is already in use)

```
    ERROR: Cannot access specified file, output.htm
```

Any suggestions guys? (Not upgrading is not an option!)

Comment: When you say *when you hit save* are you talking about File...Save in Excel or a button on the spreadsheet? In the second case, please add the code of the button's OnClick event to your question.

Comment: It's "Save" in excel. The "Auto republish to web page" function is enabled

Comment: If you can identify *at what time* the HTML will attempt a refresh (e.g., every 10 seconds at {0:00, 0:10, 0:20...} or at {0:05, 0:15, 0:25...} etc.,, you may be able control the `Save` event in Book1.xls to avoid the conflict.

Comment: Another question... if this file is being saved manually, I'm assuming it's not being updated every 10 seconds, so why use such a short interval for the refresh.html?  If you can control the interval then it would probably be easier to avoid the conflict with an event macro in the `_Save` event.

Comment: Thanks for your response, David. The file is displayed on 16 monitors across a HUGE infrastructure. It's basically a legacy system. It needs to be a relitively short refresh because the system is used to deploy resource to various locations and every minute counts. I want to know that when I hit save, the message will be displayed on the screen within 10 seconds. The other challenge I have is with 16 computers accessing this file every 10 seconds. The error occurs alot. Do you have an idea as to why this error doesn't occur in Windows XP/Office 2003? 2003 seems to just overwrite it regardless.

Comment: In a Macro, could I use a statement like IF file is in use THEN try again, until it saves successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.  I have a reduced my errors slightly by running a recursive .bat file in the backround with a 'pre' file.  Something like this.

```
REM ***********COMPARE AND COPY 1Mo MT1 RESULTS*********************
REM FILE COMPARE 7 DAY WIP(used by other sheets) WITH PRE 7 DAY WIP
FC "PATH\PREFILE.MHT" "PATH\FILE.MHT" > nul

REM IF THE FILES ARE NOT THE SAME, COPY PRE 1Mo MT1 RESULTS TO 1Mo MT1 RESULTS
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
copy /y "PATH\PREFILE.MHT" "FILE.MHT"
ECHO 1Mo MT1 Results updated at %time%
)

REM ******YOUR 10 SECOND TIMER******
TIMEOUT 10 /NOBREAK (w/out nobreak you can 'press any key to continue' past the timeout)

"PATH\THISFILE.BAT" (windows automatically opens .bats in cmd)
```

The double quotes are required if there are spaces in the path.  You can remove the File compare as that can take seconds for long files.

Hope this gets more people looking at this for a better answer, or maybe this is not an issue in Office 16.